# Linked list based Graph, Can vertex has a multiple edge?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm thinking the way to implement the graph which is linked list based. But, as far as I know, linked list can only access to next list (or previous too if doubly) and vertex from graph can access any other vertex unless it doesn't have an edge to some vertex. These two different features break my idea to build a graph.

If my vertex(or node) class(or structure) has pointer to another vertex,

```
class Vertex
{
  Vertex *link; //edge to another veretex
  int item;     //item in vertex
}
```

and my graph class looks like

```
class GraphClass
{
  Vertex **Graph;     //Graph itself
  int VertexQuantity; // number of vertex in graph
}
```

I can add vertex into graph with function addVertex() but when try to connect two vertexes, starts to losing my head. What I considering to build addEdge() function is

1. two vertexes must exist in graph
2. two vertexes shouldn't connected yet

and a function below is my addEdge() function which I'm working now.

```
void addEdge(Graph *g, Vertex *source, Vertex *destination)
{
    unsigned index, sourceIndex;
    Vertex *temp;

    // if source or destination is not exist in graph
    if((sourceIndex = searchVertex(g, source) < 0 || searchVertex(g, destination) < 0))
        return;
    // if source and destination are already connected
    if(checkConnection(g, sourceIndex, source, destination) < 0 || sourceIndex < 0)
        return;

    temp = g->Graph[sourceIndex];
    temp->link = destination;
}
```

This is my question. Let's say, v1 is vertex and connected to v2. What should I do if I wanna make a connection between v1 and v3? v1 only has its link to point some vertex, if I change vertex's next pointer as array to point multiple vertex, it breaks the rule of linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is done by having a linked list of all the nodes that your current node is connected too. If this is too confusing, start with a vector or array of pointers to all the nodes that your current node connects to, then implement that vector/array using a linked list.

Comment: Thnkas for your comment. what's your next list of v1 if v1 have an eage to v2, v3 and v4. should it be like v1->v2->v3->v4? what's the rule for choice current node's next node?

Comment: The order is not important, as long as all the nodes are present in your list. Remember, you are only trying to represent the array of neighboring nodes as a list.

Comment: In fact, I think that an array of adjacent nodes will be the better option. Look up adjacency lists for graphs.

Comment: Thanks! according to your comment, if order doesn't matter, whats the benefit to use linked list based instead of array based? An array based graph can random access which is better to find some node than linked list. But, if order doesn't matter, v1->v2->v3->v4 is slower than v1->v4->v3->v2 if we wants to find v4 from v1. Am I wrong? Still hard to understand the idea...

Comment: Oh!, I got understand meaning of your comment. Ok, order doesn't matter if current node can access to another nodes which are connected. But, still wondering v1->v2->v3->v4 is slower than v1->v4->v3->v2. Isn't it? So, if I want to connect v1 and v3 when v1 is already connected to v2, result should looks like v1->v2->v3 (or v1->v3->v2). Am I right?

Comment: Yeah you are right, arrays allow for faster access to the list of nodes. As for you other question, I think you are confusing the list of neighbouring nodes for the nodes themselves. Say v1 is connected to v2, v4, and v5. The list of v1's neighbouring nodes is v2->v4->v5. To connect v1 to v3, you will add v3 to the list of v1's neighbouring nodes, making it v2->v4->v5->v3

Comment: Thank you so much for detail comment. Array = random access, faster for search. List = less memory required than array. I got understand clearly. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! PS: hit the tick under the answer to mark the question solved.